# angular material reactive data-table keeping old state whilst fetching data over the wire

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-material

I have been following this tutorial (https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/) on how to implement an angular material data-table with pagination, sorting and filtering server side.

I wanted to expand from this by having a column to activate, de-activate a lesson with a checkbox, but only to do so when the user is ready. Only problem is that when user changes the state of a checbox, with either, search, sort or filter the old state is overwritten by what has been fetched over the wire. I can only think a few things to overcome this limitation.

1. Send update of checkbox state to endpoint as soon as we toggle the checkbox. Downside here is user doesn't have the freedom to toggle more than one checkbox box before sending over the wire.
2. Abandon server side implementation and load everything client side. Downside is first loading will take a while.

Ideally I would like to keep changes of toggling the active checkbox whilst still have the server-side feature that doesn't overwrite current state, this will allow the user to save whenever he intends to after performing multiple data-table actions.
Code wise everything is already int the tutorial (https://github.com/angular-university/angular-material-course/tree/3-dialog-finished), all I added was an additional column called active, on the template, column table array definition, and on the server's db-data

template addition...

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="active">

            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Active</mat-header-cell>

            <mat-cell class="duration-cell"
                      *matCellDef="let lesson">
                      <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="lesson.active"></mat-checkbox>
                    </mat-cell>

        </ng-container>
```

Where I think we might need to intervene is in the method that is called to retrieve data I tried merging current lessons with what is being fetched without success:

```
 this.coursesService.findLessons(courseId, filter, sortDirection,
            pageIndex, pageSize).pipe(
                catchError(() => of([])),
                finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false))
            )
            .subscribe(lessons => {
                const oldLessons = this.lessonsSubject.getValue();
                const newLessons = lessons;
                const mergedLessons = [
                    ...newLessons,
                    ...oldLessons
                ];
                console.log(mergedLessons);
                return this.lessonsSubject.next(lessons)
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to copy only the `active` property that your old data has into the objects that come from the API? Try this:

```
this.coursesService.findLessons(courseId, filter, sortDirection,
            pageIndex, pageSize)
  .pipe(
    catchError(() => of([])),
    finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false))
  ).subscribe(lessons => {
    const oldLessons = this.lessonsSubject.getValue();
    const newLessons = lessons;
    newLessons.forEach(lesson => {
      const oldLesson = oldLessons.find(l => l.id === lesson.id);
      if (oldLesson) {
        lesson.active = oldLesson.active;
      }
    });
    console.log(newLessons);
    this.lessonsSubject.next(newLessons);
  });
```

Comment: unfortunately by requesting the endpoint  with different parameter value, we request a new collection of lessons, so for example we are comparing the first 3 lessons with the next 3 lessons, and when we navigate back we are comparing those the next lessons that are now the current lessons with the previous lessons.

Comment: In this case, loosing the selection would qualify as "normal behavior" because the user did not select them, right?

Comment: If he unchecks for example the frst 3 items that were checked, then he navigates to the next 3 items, the comparison logic is done and since none have matching id nothing will be done, so far so good. But now if we go back, we fetch again the first 3 items, and their ids do not match the ids of the next 3 items (from previous page), so again nothing is done and the value from the backend is again displayed, so we lose the local state that we changed. Hope that is clear

Comment: Yes, it's more clear now. You could save the ids of the checked lessons in a service and check those whenever you fetch the data and set the `lesson.active` property if the id is found in the marked lessons array.

Comment: I see, so with this service I can store or update a list of object with id and isChecked value in the component whenever I check. and in the datasource I could map by id and update the checked value if it exists with the help of that same service whenever I search over the wire for new data. I will give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I have come up with:

I created a simple solution with a service that keeps track of active lessons its key is the lesson id and value the checked status

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable( {providedIn: 'root'})
export class ActiveTrackerService {
    public activeRules = {};
}
```

I attached a change event to each checbox that will be used to update the service with the changes.

```
 toggleActivateRule($event, lesson){
        this.activeTrackerService.activeRules = {
            ...this.activeTrackerService.activeRules,
            [lesson.id]: $event.checked
        } 
    }
```

Finally, in the dataSource, whenever we retrive a list of lessons from the endpoint
we use the activeTracker service again only this time it is to see the lessons that had their active status changed and modify the new list accordingly when we map over it.

```
  const newLessons = lessons.map( lesson => {
                    const isModifiedLesson = typeof this.activeTrackerService.activeRules[lesson.id] === 'boolean'
                    const hasValueChanged = this.activeTrackerService.activeRules[lesson.id] !== lesson.id
                    if(isModifiedLesson && hasValueChanged) {
                            lesson.active = this.activeTrackerService.activeRules[lesson.id];
                    }
                    return lesson;
                });
                return this.lessonsSubject.next(newLessons);
```

This may not be the most maintainable solution, what if there are mutliple tables with multiple values to track and only one datasource as source of truth, it will quickly start to become unmaintainable, would like your thoughhts on a better solution.